# Spring batch MongoDB trade-offs vs Spring batch MySQL

Tags: mongodb, spring-batch

I've used Spring Batch with MySQL before and the availability of Spring Batch Admin makes the starting, stopping, restarting of Jobs a lot easier. But my current company is considering to move to MongoDB from Derby database for obvious NoSQL DB benefits and also wants to move their existing messy batch application solutions to use Spring Batch framework. They also would like to use Spring Batch's Admin for managing the jobs.

**Question:**
What are the tradeoffs that we will have to make for using Spring Batch with MongoDB then Spring Batch with MySQL?

After doing a bit of research I've gathered the following trade-offs for using MongoDB with Spring batch

- Since MongoDB does not support transactions, Spring Batch Admin will not work since the Admin requires the meta-data schema which is not available for MongoDB.
- We will not be able to Stop, Start & restart jobs.
- If a Step's writer tries committing 20 documents and commit for 1 document fails, the other 19 documents will not be rolled back automatically and will have to be managed by the system.

Can you please tell me if I am right with the above and if there are any other that I have not mentioned already.

Comment: Is there a possibility to use MySQL for Spring Batch alone and keep MongoDB for business data?